# Desktop App Converter -PackageName E_MANIFEST_USE_DEFAULT_VALUE_FAILED

Tags: uwp, windows-store-apps, windows-store, desktop-bridge, desktop-app-converter

I am trying to convert my app to an appx using Desktop App Converter.

I am trying to use my Package/Identity/Name from the Microsoft store dashboard in the form of -PackageName "1234Myapp.Andthistoo".

Desktop App Converter will not take it.It keeps coming back with a write error.

From my searches I have been under the impression that the -PackageName category can not start with a number and it can not contain a period which my Package/Identity/Name contains both.

It fails with this message:

DesktopAppConverter : error 'E_MANIFEST_SET_PROPERTY_FAILED': Property 'Package.Identity.Name' in AppxManifest.xml
could not be set to the value '123MyApps.MyAppsproject' given for parameter -'PackageName'. Please visit:
'https://aka.ms/idname' for more info on the Data type requirements for the property.
At line:1 char:1
+ &'C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.DesktopAppConverter_1.0.9.0_ ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,DesktopAppConverter.ps1

When I got to the identity information page it says:

Identity Name = A string between 3 and 50 characters in length that consists of alpha-numeric, period, and dash characters.

I can not see what I am doing wrong

Comment: It should be something like `Microsoft.Office.OneNote_8wekyb3d8bbwe`

Comment: tried that still the same

Comment: Does your app's name actually start with "123"?

Comment: No the four numbers it starts with are the package identity name from the dashboard

Comment: Please duplicate of [Desktop App Converter -PackageName Error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43028693/desktop-app-converter-packagename-error), thanks.

Comment: hi, did you actually solve your problem? I am facing a similar issue. similar, but not exactly same error...