# Desktop App Converter what to put as a -PackageName

Tags: uwp, windows-store-apps, windows-store, desktop-bridge, desktop-app-converter

I am trying to make an appx file for the store using Desktop App Converter.

In my command I put the `-PackageName` from the Package/Identity/Name from the Microsoft store dashboard.

But Desktop App Converter stops with:

> DesktopAppConverter : error 'E_MANIFEST_SET_PROPERTY_FAILED': Property 'Package.Identity.Name' in AppxManifest.xml could not be set to the value '123MyApps.MyAppsproject' given for parameter -'PackageName'. Please visit: 'https://aka.ms/idname' for more info on the Data type requirements for the property. At line:1 char:1 + &'C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.DesktopAppConverter_1.0.9.0_ ... + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ + CategoryInfo : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,DesktopAppConverter.ps1

If I use the display name eg. "MyApps", it works. But when I submit it to the store I get:

> Invalid package identity name: MyApps (expected: 1234MyApps.MyApps)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Desktop App Converter -PackageName E\_MANIFEST\_USE\_DEFAULT\_VALUE\_FAILED](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43009587/desktop-app-converter-packagename-e-manifest-use-default-value-failed)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows 10 UWP - detect if the current internet connection is Wifi or Cellular?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32845625/windows-10-uwp-detect-if-the-current-internet-connection-is-wifi-or-cellular)