# Desktop App Converter -PackageName Error

Tags: windows-store-apps, windows-store, desktop-bridge, desktop-app-converter

I am trying to convert my app for the windows store using Desktop App Converter.

If I set the -PackageName option to the Package/Identity/Name given in the dashboard, Desktop App Converter stops with a write error for -PackageName.

But if I put -PackageName to the display name that I want, when I submit the appx file to the windows store I get: Invalid package identity name: and Invalid package family name:

*update

My Pakage/Identity/name takes the form 1234MyApp.MyApp.
If I leave out the '1234' then Desktop App Converter completes its run. But of course when I try to submit the appx file to the windows store I the Invalid package identity name and Invalid package family name errors.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Desktop App Converter -PackageName E\_MANIFEST\_USE\_DEFAULT\_VALUE\_FAILED](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43009587/desktop-app-converter-packagename-e-manifest-use-default-value-failed)

Answer (score 0):

You're supposed to use your own package name as the `Package Name` in Desktop App Converter so that you could manage to generate the appx package.

Then you will need to open the Package Manifest.xml to modify the `Package Identity Name` to match the value in Dev Center in order to upload it to the Windows Store.

By the way, you need to fill in and submit [this form](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/projects/campaigns/desktop-bridge) to acquire the permission to publish the Desktop converted app to the Store.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. That is my problem. After I alter the Package Identity Name in my Package Manifest xml, do I need to run Desktop App Converter again as the only item I can submit is the appx file and not the manifest. I have the permissions needed.

Comment: @gerry You do not need to run DAC tool again. After altering the identity info in Package Manifest xml, you can use [MakeAppx.exe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/hh446767(v=vs.85).aspx) to repackage it to generate an appx. Then you can upload it to Dev Center.

Comment: I used MakeAppx.exe to unpack and then repack the app. In the AppxManifest when I change Identity Name, an appx package is made but when I go to install it its stops with "Cannot open appx/appxbundle file Reason: Failed due to unknown reason". When I change Application Id, Makeappx stops with an error that my appname violates pattern constraint

Comment: Can you manage to upload your package to Dev Center after generating the appx with new package identity name? How do you sideload that appx?

Comment: The form link no longer works. I can't find a reference to it on that web site. Is that formality still required?

Answer (score -1):

I just came across this issue today and was able to solve it by using the windows store package name that would be your "1234MyApp.MyApp" with an AppId of something else like maybe your executable name "MyApp.exe".

My PowerShell looked something like...

```
$publisher = "1234MyApp.MyApp"
$appId = "MyApp.exe"

DesktopAppConverter -Installer $binDirectory -AppExecutable InventoryAudit.WpfApp.exe -Destination $packageDirectory -AppId $appId -PackageName $packageName -Publisher $publisher -AppDisplayName $appDisplayName -AppDescription $appDescription -PackageDisplayName $packageDisplayName -PackagePublisherDisplayName $packagePublisherDisplayName -Verbose -MakeAppx -Version $version
```

I only provided the relevant variables.  Hope this helps the next person to have this issue.